# How to validate Go object data like Javascript's Joi?

Tags: go

I use [Joi](https://www.npmjs.com/package/joi) to do object schema and data validation in JavaScript. In Golang, I know how to do schema validation, but how do I do data validation?

Is there a Joi equivalient for Golang? I am aware of Godog, but it hasn't reached 1.0 yet.

Comment: It depends on, what you want... What is the context of your validation? Maybe a framework like Gobuffalo could help you. Do you valdiate, before you write the data into a db? Or do you want to check a dump?

Comment: Look for `govalidator` package.

Comment: @apxp I want to validate the data that I received before writing in to a db or send it to some other component. What do you suggest?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try ozzo-validation https://github.com/go-ozzo/ozzo-validation

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "regexp"

    "github.com/go-ozzo/ozzo-validation"
    "github.com/go-ozzo/ozzo-validation/is"
)

type Address struct {
    Street string
    City   string
    State  string
    Zip    string
}

func (a Address) Validate() error {
    return validation.ValidateStruct(&a,
        // Street cannot be empty, and the length must between 5 and 50
        validation.Field(&a.Street, validation.Required, validation.Length(5, 50)),
        // City cannot be empty, and the length must between 5 and 50
        validation.Field(&a.City, validation.Required, validation.Length(5, 50)),
        // State cannot be empty, and must be a string consisting of two letters in upper case
        validation.Field(&a.State, validation.Required, validation.Match(regexp.MustCompile("^[A-Z]{2}$"))),
        // State cannot be empty, and must be a string consisting of five digits
        validation.Field(&a.Zip, validation.Required, validation.Match(regexp.MustCompile("^[0-9]{5}$"))),
    )
}

func main() {
    a := Address{
        Street: "123",
        City:   "Unknown",
        State:  "Virginia",
        Zip:    "12345",
    }

    err := a.Validate()
    fmt.Println(err)
    // Output:
    // Street: the length must be between 5 and 50; State: must be in a valid format.
}
```

Comment: Great tip, just curious about the performance trade-offs on using this kind of validation.